# Replicaset doesnot update pods in when pod image is modified

Tags: kubernetes, replicaset

I have created a replicaset with wrong container image with below configuration.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: rs-d33393
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: busybox-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: busybox-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - echo Hello Kubernetes! && sleep 3600
        image: busyboxXXXXXXX
        name: busybox-container
```

Pods Information:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME              READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
rs-d33393-5hnfx   0/1       InvalidImageName   0          11m
rs-d33393-5rt5m   0/1       InvalidImageName   0          11m
rs-d33393-ngw78   0/1       InvalidImageName   0          11m
rs-d33393-vnpdh   0/1       InvalidImageName   0          11m
```

After this, i try to edit the image inside replicaset using **kubectl edit replicasets.extensions rs-d33393** and update image as **busybox**.

Now, i am expecting pods to be recreated with proper image as part of replicaset.

This has not been the exact result.

Can someone please explain, why it is so?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `ReplicaSets` directly you have to kill the old pod, so the new ones will be created with the right image.

If you would be using a `Deployment`, and you should, changing the image would force the pod to be re-created.

Answer (score 9):

`Replicaset` does not support updates. As long as required number of pods exist matching the selector labels, replicaset's jobs is done. You should use `Deployment` instead.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/

From the docs:

> To update Pods to a new spec in a controlled way, use a Deployment, as
>   ReplicaSets do not support a rolling update directly.

Answer (score 3):

Deployment is a higher-level concept that manages ReplicaSets and provides declarative updates to Pods. Therefore, **it is recommend to use Deployments instead of directly using ReplicaSets unless you don’t require updates at all**. ( i.e. one may never need to manipulate ReplicaSet objects when using a Deployment)

Its easy to perform rolling updates and rollbacks when deployed using deployments.

```
$ kubectl create deployment busybox --image=busyboxxxxxxx --dry-run -o yaml > busybox.yaml

$ cat busybox.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: busybox
  name: busybox
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: busybox
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: busybox
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: busyboxxxxxxx
        name: busyboxxxxxxx
```

```
ubuntu@dlv-k8s-cluster-master:~$ kubectl create -f busybox.yaml --record=true
deployment.apps/busybox created
```

**Check rollout history**

```
ubuntu@dlv-k8s-cluster-master:~$ kubectl rollout history deployment busybox
deployment.apps/busybox
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         kubectl create --filename=busybox.yaml --record=true
```

**Update image on deployment**

```
ubuntu@dlv-k8s-cluster-master:~$ kubectl set image deployment.app/busybox *=busybox --record
deployment.apps/busybox image updated


ubuntu@dlv-k8s-cluster-master:~$ kubectl rollout history deployment busybox
deployment.apps/busybox
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         kubectl create --filename=busybox.yaml --record=true
2         kubectl set image deployment.app/busybox *=busybox --record=true
```

**Rollback Deployment**

```
ubuntu@dlv-k8s-cluster-master:~$ kubectl rollout undo deployment busybox
deployment.apps/busybox rolled back


ubuntu@dlv-k8s-cluster-master:~$ kubectl rollout history deployment busybox
deployment.apps/busybox
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
2         kubectl set image deployment.app/busybox *=busybox --record=true
3         kubectl create --filename=busybox.yaml --record=true
```

Comment: D.T., thanks for your detailed explanation. 
I will refer documentation and do some more practise with deployments.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
k scale rs new-replica-set --replicas=0
```

and then

```
k scale rs new-replica-set --replicas=<Your number of replicas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the replicaset(assuming its called replicaset.yaml) file with command:

```
kubectl edit rs replicaset
```

- edit the image name in the editor
- save the file
- exit the editor

Now , you will need to either delete the replica sets or delete the existing pods:

```
kubectl delete rs new-replica-set
            
kubectl delete pod pod_1 pod_2 pod_2 pod_4
```

replicaset should spin up new pods with new image.

Answer (score 0):

edit the configuration, set the replica to 0. then use

```
kubectl replace -f your_definition_file.yml
```

then again edit the configuration, set the replica to 4, then use

```
kubectl replace -f your_definition_file.yml
```